# argparse telling me a store_true arg needs an argument all of a sudden

Tags: python, ipython, argparse

I'm using the `argparse` library and have a few boolean arguments created like this:

```
import argparse 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Generate a batch of Line Protocol points of a specified shape")
    parser.add_argument('--loop', action='store_true', help="If True, script runs in infinit loop; used with Telegraf `execd` input plugin")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(args)
```

This has worked for weeks with no issue and now all of a sudden I'm getting the error:

```
ipython3: error: argument --loop: expected one argument
```

Comment: any reproducible code will be helpful.

Comment: Please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the full error message:

```
0814:~/mypy$ ipython3 --loop
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--debug] [--quiet] [--init] [--autoindent] [--no-autoindent] [--automagic]
                [--no-automagic] [--pdb] [--no-pdb] [--pprint] [--no-pprint] [--color-info]
                [--no-color-info] [--ignore-cwd] [--no-ignore-cwd] [--nosep] [--autoedit-syntax]
                [--no-autoedit-syntax] [--simple-prompt] [--no-simple-prompt] [--banner] [--no-banner]
                [--confirm-exit] [--no-confirm-exit] [--term-title] [--no-term-title] [--classic]
                [--quick] [-i] [--profile-dir ProfileDir.location]
                [--profile TerminalIPythonApp.profile] [--ipython-dir TerminalIPythonApp.ipython_dir]
                [--log-level TerminalIPythonApp.log_level]
                [--config TerminalIPythonApp.extra_config_file]
                [--autocall TerminalInteractiveShell.autocall]
                [--colors TerminalInteractiveShell.colors] [--logfile TerminalInteractiveShell.logfile]
                [--logappend TerminalInteractiveShell.logappend] [-c TerminalIPythonApp.code_to_run]
                [-m TerminalIPythonApp.module_to_run] [--ext TerminalIPythonApp.extra_extensions]
                [--gui TerminalIPythonApp.gui] [--pylab [TerminalIPythonApp.pylab]]
                [--matplotlib [TerminalIPythonApp.matplotlib]]
                [--cache-size TerminalInteractiveShell.cache_size]
                [extra_args [extra_args ...]]
ipython3: error: argument --loop: expected one argument
1240:~/mypy$
```

Comment: Yes -- also, I've updated with repro code in case that helps

Comment: That usage message tells us that it is `ipython` that's complaining, not your own parser.

Comment: Yep, that's the issue -- not sure why that is

Comment: `ipython` takes input from the commandline.  You need to pay attention to its `help`.

Comment: You need to call it like this `ipython3 -- --loop` (see answer above)

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following file (`example.py`):

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--loop', action='store_true', help="<help stuff")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

you can execute it either with "plain" Python:

```
$ python example.py 
Namespace(loop=False)

$ python example.py --loop
Namespace(loop=True)
```

or with ipython, where you need to separate ipython arguments with script arguments by `--`:

```
$ ipython3 example.py -- --loop
Namespace(loop=True)
```